# What addresses do have captures in a C++ lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda

I wrote the following code to investigate on address of a capture inside a
lambda expression

```
 # include <iostream>
 # include <functional>
 using fu = std::function<void(int)>;

 void f(fu l, int x)
  { l(x); }

 int main()
  {
   double d{1.17};
   int i = 12;
   char a = 'a';
   // write addresses on stdout:
   std::cout << "address of d in main is " << &d << std::endl;
   std::cout << "address of i in main is " << &i << std::endl;
   std::cout << "address of a in main is 0x" 
             << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<long>(&a) << std::dec 
             << std::endl;

   // now let us introduce a lambda expr as follows
   auto l = [&, i, a](int y)
    {
     std::cout<<"captured d by reference " << d
              <<" at address " << &d << std::endl;
     std::cout<<"captured i by value " << i
              <<" at address " << &i << std::endl;
     std::cout<<"captured a by value " << a
              <<" at address 0x" << std::hex
              << reinterpret_cast<long>(&a) << std::dec
              << std::endl;
     std::cout<<"got parameter " << y
              <<" at address " << &y << std::endl;
    };
  // now send the lambda to f which will execute it
  f(l, i);
  }
```

When this code is run a "typical output" looks like:

```
   address of d in main is 0x7ffd96bc4628
   address of i in main is 0x7ffd96bc4624
   address of a in main is 0x7ffd96bc4623
   captured d by reference 1.17 at address 0x7ffd96bc4628
   captured i by value 12 at address 0x7ffd96bc4630
   captured a by value a at address 0x7ffd96bc4634
   got parameter 12 at address 0x7ffd96bc4564
```

In that output I can easily understand:

1) the relative values of addresses in `main`

2) the identity of address for the captured by reference `d`

3) the different addresses of the captured by value `i` and `a`

4) the completely different address of the local parameter `y`

5) the relative values of the addresses of the captured `i` and `a`

But it is hard to understand, for me, the relative value of the address
of the captured `i` with respect to the captured `d`: they seem to be,
if I'm not wrong, ONLY TWO bytes apart from each other.

What do this mean? That the addresses of `i` and `d` (and also of `a`) INSIDE the lambda scope do overlap...?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: They're in hexadecimal, and 0x10 - 0x8 = 16 - 8 = 8.

Answer (score 3):

Because **0x30 - 0x28 = 0x8**.

This is hex, not dec, so the number sequence should be

```
0x28 0x29 0x2a 0x2b 0x2c 0x2d 0x2e 0x2f 0x30 ...
```

If it were decimal number, it would have been

```
28 29 30 ...
```

But here it's not.

Answer (score 1):

> But it is hard to understand, for me, the relative value of the address of the captured i with respect to the captured d: they seem to be, if I'm not wrong, ONLY TWO bytes apart from each other.

You are wrong, 28 and 30 in hex are 8 bytes apart  - when you subtract in decimal you borrow 10 (base of decimal), in hex you borrow 16 (base for hex) so 16 - 8 == 8

Comment: Oh, yeah, that was silly. I didn't consider that, even after having explicitly used the `hex` manipulator to make the output uniform...